# How to disable an A hyperlink in Chrome like in IE

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome

In IE a `<a href="javascript:;></a>` can be disabled by setting property `disabled="true"`, but it does not work for Chrome. I don't want it trigger any event while clicking. (`event.preventDefault(), event.stopPropagation()` don't work for me).
How can I disable it in Chrome just like in IE?

Thanks!

Comment: Try `<a href='#'>` but you must remember to `return false` in your onclick method to stop the page scrolling back to the top - this will work in all browsers afaik

Comment: Add a class `class="disabled"` and put this in the css: `a.disabled { pointer-events: none; }`

Comment: Why are you using an anchor element in the first place if you do not want its default behavior? Just use a `span`.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using `<a href="javascript:;></a>`

Why not use, `<a onclick="javascript:;></a>`?

```js
function helloWorld() {
  alert("Hello World!");
}
```

```html
<a onclick="helloWorld()">Click Me</a>
```

Comment: It will not look like a link on hover if you don't put href attribute, may be this is the reason.